# Setting 2 different backgrounds for a view

Tags: iphone, view, transparency, xib, background-color

I have a view, which is divided into 2 parts. On the top half of the view I want a blue background and on the bottom half I want a transparent background. I am not sure if it can be done.
 Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. By far the easiest is to simply create a subview in the top half of the view with a blue background. Other methods include adding a sublayer or overriding `drawRect` with custom drawing code.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to create a single view then you have to create a image file with 2 parts

upper part is blue and bottom half is transparent

else you need to create two view with different background

Comment: create an image is not related to iphone coding. create other uiview you can just work with interface builder.  drawrect is a good method and related to iphone coding